# Пояснить отрывок кода на javascript

Tags: javascript

Прошу пояснить словами что в нем происходит, соответственно для дальнейшего обучения.

```
 var sum=0;
 for (var i=0; i < vals.length; i++){
    sum = sum + parseInt(vals[i]);
 }
```

Comment: в чем тут jquery?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом коде, создаётся переменная `sum` равная 0.
Потом идёт цикл от 0 до длины массива `vals`, и каждую итерацию цикла, в sum записывается ее ткущее значение, плюс элемент массива `vals` Который приводится к числу, с номером текущей итерации цикла.

Comment: _"плюс элемент массива"_ - да ну? А `parseInt` не у дел?

Comment: Хорошо, дополню ответ.

Comment: А может стоит дать ответ чуть более высокоуровневый (в смысле не просто пересказывая код, а описать, что он делает). Например, этот код **вычисляет сумму всех чисел в массиве vals**

Comment: Ну, мы точно не знаем что делает этот код, вдруг в vals не только числа, и вообще это тест.